# Zend Framework: Get CPU usage

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I get CPU usage in Zend Framework, because when I open some page with some browser my CPU usage increased to 100%? I use AppServ 2.5.10: Apache 2.2.8, PHP 5.2.6, MySQL 5.0.51b, my PC config: AMD Athlon 64 X2 2.21Ghz, 4GB RAM DDR2.

Comment: Which CPU usage goes to 100%  Your PC/browser or the server?

Comment: My CPU usage normaly is 15%, but when I open some page with browser up to 100%. Httpd.conf file up from 0.1% to 35% maximum, firefox up to 30-35%. Is this normal?

Comment: It can be, if the system wants to use 100% CPU to serve a request as quickly as possible then its okay.  As long as your load average is low and requests are handled quickly high CPU usage just means the CPU is doing something.  Firefox will use a lot of CPU to render pages, more so if there is Flash content, scripted animations, moving images, or lots of canvas/SVG drawing.

Comment: How do I know if this is true?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) to profile your application. Not only it will give you a whole slew of metrics to study (CPU and memory usage, among others), but also you'll be able to see the real chokepoints of your application.